# How to swap first 2 consecutive different bits

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

What would be a fast and elegant way to swap the first (least significant) 2 different consecutive bits in an unsigned integer?

E.g.

```
100100 -> 100010
110011 -> 110101
```

So far I came up with this:

```
unsigned long long special_swap(unsigned long long number)
{
    if (number & 1)
        return (number + 1) ^ ((number ^ (number + 1)) >> 2);
    number = ~number;
    return ~((number + 1) ^ ((number ^ (number + 1)) >> 2));
}
```

My biggest discontent with the above solution is that it uses the `if` instruction.

Comment: What is first? Leftmost? Rightmost?

Comment: Interesting: https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#SwappingBitsXOR

Comment: Build a hash table of all 256 possible states a byte can be in and the transformation you want.  Then just do the look up.  Repeat for the next byte if needed.

Comment: @i_am_jorf and then the challenge is to handle the `unsigned long long`: it has 7 boundaries where adjacent bit pairs cross byte boundaries.

Comment: @i_am_jorf If you could see me tilt my head... you'd know I'm awaiting your demo implementation o.O

Comment: Yeah, you're right.  Nevermind.

Comment: Isn't the first example `100100 -> 011000` ? Or could someone explain the problem a little more clearly?

Comment: @personjerry, you start from right to left, detect first 2 bits that differ, and swap them. The goal is to detect the closest number which has the same number of bits set to 1.

Comment: BTW, is it an academic exercise, or do you have an application for this? Just curious.

Comment: @Rémi, just a problem for technical interviews.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

```
unsigned long long my_swap(unsigned long long number)
{
 unsigned long long x = number ^ (number >> 1);
 return number ^ ((x & -x) * 3);
}
```

My solution returns 0 when number == 0, whereas the function of the original question returns 1100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.

Some explanations: the bits of x contain 0 if the bit at this position is equal to the next bit, and 1 if it is different. (x & -x) is the least significant bit of x, that is to say the first bit difference.

Comment: I considered the function undefined in 0, so that's fine. How did you come up with x ^ (x >> 1), what does that achieve?

Comment: Note: this function also has a case that is not handled "as expected": when all bits are 1, it sets the highest bit to 0. However the function from the question (and my version of it) set the two highest bits to 0. Anyway: that's a very nice solution!

Comment: @alain, i guess I would consider the case when all bits are 1 also as undefined, since the correct result would overflow (e.g. for 4 bits integers 1111 -> 10111). I chose this as accepted answer because I found it easier to understand and it doesn't differentiate between 0 and 1 bits.

Comment: @gg.kaspersky I just wanted to mention it for completeness. I think I would also have accepted this answer ;-)

Answer (score 3):

This is the same idea without using an `if`.

```
unsigned long long special_swap(unsigned long long number)
{
    unsigned long long t = ((number & 1) << 1) - 1;
    return (number + t) ^ ((number ^ (number + t)) >> 2);
}
```

The variable `t` is either 1 or -1, depending on the lsb of the number.

<kbd>[Test it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7355e4d8509fe43d)</kbd>